# When configuring Glibc prior to compiling it I recieve an error concerning kernel headers telling me to use "--with-headers"

Tags: compiling, glibc, lfs

I am using the latest stable Linux from Scratch book version. In [Step 5.5.1](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter05/glibc.html), when configuring Glibc I run the provided script, and receive an error telling me to use the --with-headers configure option, however I am already using it.

The book states to configure using:

```
../configure \ --prefix=/usr \ --host=$LFS_TGT \ --build=$(../scripts/config.guess) \ --enable-kernel=3.2 \ --with-headers=$LFS/usr/include \ libc_cv_slibdir=/lib
```

When doing so I receive the following error:

```
checking installed Linux kernel header files... missing or too old!
configure: error: GNU libc requires kernel header files from
Linux 3.2.0 or later to be installed before configuring.
The kernel header files are found usually in /usr/include/asm and
/usr/include/linux; make sure these directories use files from
Linux 3.2.0 or later.  This check uses <linux/version.h>, so
make sure that file was built correctly when installing the kernel header
files.  To use kernel headers not from /usr/include/linux, use the
configure option --with-headers.
```

Any advise on how to proceed would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. Simple error on my part. In case someone else runs into this in the future: In the previous step (5.4.1) there may have been an error in the installation of the Linux headers, and to run "cp -rv usr/include $LFS/usr" root may be required. In my case I must have missed this specific command, thus in the next step there were simply no headers for glibc to work with.